# Is there a standard projection for Sub-Saharan Africa?

Tags: coordinate-system, d3

With the help of d3.js, TopoJSON, and data from [Glottolog](http://glottolog.org/) I have made [this map of Bantu languages](http://bl.ocks.org/SuzanaK/c16c9d616b9aafe2c23e) that exist in Sub-Saharan Africa.

I've used the standard Mercator projection so far. I know that there are always tradeoffs between different projection properties but I'd like to know if there is some standard projection that is recommended for Sub-Saharan Africa other than Mercator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are "near" the equator, the cylindrical projections (like Mercator) work well (not too many distortions). If you want to be perfectly fair in terms of areas, you could use cylindrical equal area or sinusoidal projection. But this would not markedly differ from Mercator.

Comment: Is cylindrical equal area the same as [Lambert's conformal conic projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#conicConformal) implemented in d3.js?

Comment: Lambert conformal is, as its name says, a conformal projection (keeps the "shapes", not the areas). Also the conic projections are better for mid latitude: I would not use them near the equator.